# Control if Image is loaded VB.Net WP8

Tags: vb.net, image, http, windows-phone-8

The following code downloads Image from http-website.

```
Dim path As String
path = "http://example.com/img/1.jpg"

ZImage.UriSource = New Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
XImage.Source = ZImage
```

Image is invisible by default, after picture is loaded (it can take time 1-2 sec) I must show this Image to a user.
How can I control that image is loaded?

Note:
Imagebox is Empty, when script start runing. When app starts downloading picture from the Web, it takes 1-2 seconds, sometimes 3, after that Imagebox shows picture, but before that is just black rectangle. I need to show ImageBox when picture is loaded fully to the ImageBox, not when it is just black rectangle. How can i control, if picture is fully loaded and is allowed to be shown to a user?

Comment: What do you mean by `control that image is loaded`?

Comment: Imagebox is Empty, when script start runing. When app starts downloading picture from the Web, it takes 1-2 seconds, sometimes 3, after that Imagebox shows picture, but before that is just black rectangle. I need to show ImageBox when picture is loaded fully to the ImageBox, not when it is just black rectangle. How can i control, if picture is fully loaded and is allowed to be shown to a user?

Comment: Do not post that as a comment. Edit and improve your question.

Comment: You could wait until the image has downloaded before creating the imagebox which shows it.

Comment: Andrew, how can I know how long I need to wait 1src or 2sec or 3sec? If it is possible to control image downloading status, it can give answer...

Comment: I'm not able to try out actual code at the moment, so I will point you to [Windows Phone 8 Tutorial: Loading an Image from the Network](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/nicholas-cipollina/windows-phone-8-tutorial-loading-image-the-network).